Cohomology of current algebras in higher dimensions
I am interested in the cohomology of current algebras in $n$ dimensions with coefficients in non-trivial modules. An $n$-dimensional current algebra is a Lie algebra of smooth functions on ${\mathbb R}^n$ valued in a finite-dimensional Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$, with the obvious Lie bracket. The modules I am interested in are spaces of smooth functions on ${\mathbb R}^n$ valued in some finite-dimensional ${\mathfrak g}$-module. The cohomology is understood in the Gelfand-Fuks sense. The well-known book by Fuks only considers cohomology of current algebras in dimension 1 and only for trivial modules. What is known about $n>1$? For example, is anything known about the degree-1 cohomology?
P.S. I am mostly interested in the case of semi-simple ${\mathfrak g}$.

See Theorems 2.1 and 3.7 in arXiv:math/0302334 for the computation of $H^1$ and $H^2$. Perhaps the author @PashaZusmanovich could chime in with more details!

This looks similar to what I need, but I do not understand the second sentence of the paper already: "Namely, let L be a Lie algebra, M an L-module, A an associative commutative algebra with unit, V a symmetric unital A-module." What is a "symmetric A-module"?

Symmetric module means a bimodule whose left and right actions coincide. Will be glad to be of further assistance, preferably at pasha.zusmanovich@gmail.com
